# Pdf download encoding wrong

Tags: angularjs, spring, pdf, typescript, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've uploaded a pdf file to my database and now I'm trying to download it again.
The uploading part should be fine since when I go in oracle sql developper I can download it and it shows my original text.

At this moment I can download the file and open it without errors but the content is gone and its just an empty pdf.
[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf69i8uhshsciom/rapport%20%286%29.pdf?dl=0)
[What it should be](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v8vndhrlh2bvqa/Rapport.pdf?dl=0)

I've written a custom controller to return my pdf

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/rapport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Resource<String> resource = null;
    try {
        String file = new String(dossierRepository.findOne(id).getRapport(), "UTF-8");
        resource = new Resource<>(file);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DossierController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
}
```

And then I download this with the following function using typescript/angular/ngFileSaver.

```
public openFunc(item: any, column: any): void {
    if(column === "rapport"){
        item.customGET("rapport").then(
            (data: any): void => {
                let blob:Blob = new Blob([data.content], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                this.FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'rapport.pdf');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I've found on other questions that pdf is a multipart file and that some of the content is in other formats but isn't it possible to just download the data like I'm able in Oracle SQL developper?

I suppose the encoding is wrong but if I look at [oracle's blob mapping page](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefjdbc96386.html#rrefjdbc96386) it says that blob's are encoded in UTF-8 so I don't know what I'm doin wrong.

**EDIT**

My getFile now looks like this to check wether Resource returns a valid file (it doesn't)

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/rapport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Resource<String> resource = null;
    try {
        String file = new String(dossierRepository.findOne(id).getRapport(), "UTF-8");
        resource = new Resource<>(file);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Sam\\files\\Masterproef lca\\lca-analysebeheer\\Test-Files\\rapporttest.pdf"));
            writer.write(resource.getContent());
        }
        catch (IOException e)...
```

Just writing the string also doesn't give me the correct file (UTF-8 or empty , both wrong result).

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/rapport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Resource<String> resource = null;
    try {
        String file = new String(dossierRepository.findOne(id).getRapport(), "UTF-8");
        resource = new Resource<>(file);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Sam\\files\\Masterproef lca\\lca-analysebeheer\\Test-Files\\rapporttest.pdf"));
            writer.write(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e)...
```

Trying to write out the byte[]

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/rapport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Resource<byte[]> resource = null;
    try {    
        resource = new Resource<>(dossierRepository.findOne(id).getRapport());

        Path path;
        path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Sam\\files\\Masterproef lca\\lca-analysebeheer\\Test-Files\\rapportTestBytes.pdf");
        Files.write(path, resource.getContent());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
```

gives the [following](https://www.dropbox.com/s/flmz7px75g0fack/rapport%20%2812%29.pdf?dl=0) unreadable pdf of encoded bytes.

I tried writing the file before I wrote it to my database

```
String postRapport(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam("rapport") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("Entered custom file upload with id " + id + " and name " + file.getName());
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Dossier dossier = dossierRepository.findOne(id);
            dossier.setRapport(bytes);

            dossierRepository.save(dossier);
            Path path;
            path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Sam\\files\\Masterproef lca\\lca-analysebeheer\\Test-Files\\uploaddatabytesS.pdf");
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            return "You successfully uploaded " + file.getName() + " into " + file.getName() + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e)
```

And that returned a correct pdf file so it's not in writing my file that I'm going wrong.
I really don't know what to look for further so any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you save `Resource<String>` locally?  Is it a valid file?

Comment: @KKKKKKKK I've added an example file of what I get when I download

Comment: Right.  But instead of `getFile()` returning it to HTTP, have you saved it locally?  Is it a valid file?

Comment: The "what it should be" is the original. I've uploaded that to my database and if download it there with oracle-sql developper it's still a valid file with the correct content. Everything I dowload trough the getFile is valid to the point that I can open it without getting an error but it is empty. What other way do you propose that I download it?

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, you need to test whether or not `Resource<String>` is returning a valid file.  So under `resource = new Resource<>(file)`, can you do `resource.SaveStringAs('path/to/save');` or something?

Comment: @KKKKKKKK the Resource<String> indeed also doesn't return a valid file.
It's the same as my example dropbox link.

Comment: Please check whether there is a way to construct a `Resource` from a `byte[]` because already interpreting the PDF bytes as a UTF-8 encoded `String` will break its contents. If possible, try `new Resource<>(dossierRepository.findOne(id).getRapport())` or a factory method to that effect.

Comment: @mkl writing out the byte stream gives it completely encoded and my entire problem is that I don't know how to decode it. Getting it in the resource isn't the problem.

Comment: *completely encoded* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's something like JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tb... instead of %PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj.....
At [this](https://www.base64decode.org/) online decoder you can get a decoding that looks similar to my second desired format but again unreadable since I don't know what format I should select.

Comment: You can see what I mean if you open the file-links I included in a text editor.